# How can I disable latex rendering in ipython 7?

Tags: python, ipython

When I run the following code:

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
p = Polynomial([1, 2])
print(p)
print(p.__repr__())
print(p.__str__())
```

all three print commands give me text output, yet when I type 'p' in the console, I get a typeset image rendition of the polynomial.  Is there a config setting in ipython (or anywhere else) to disable this and just get simple ascii or unicode?

"Spyder|Preferences|IPython console|Advanced settings|Use symbolic math" is unchecked.

Comment: This is still unsolved and annoying, in case anyone has a suggestion for me...I would be grateful!